# Access constructor in scala

Tags: scala

I have scala code like this:

```
 class PW(instance: S) extends MLW with S {
 override def save(path: String): Unit = {

 if(instance.isInstanceOf[ISPM])
   {
     val mod = instance.asInstanceOf[ISPM]
      new PM(mod.u, mod.s).w.save(path)

   }
}
}

class ISPM(override val u: String,
           override val s: Array[T]) extends PM(u, s) {
```

ISPM extends PM.
new PM(mod.u, mod.s).w(path)--> this is failing with error: constructor PM in class PM cannot be accessed in class PW

I don't have access to modify the constructor/class PM
How can I access constructor PM from class PW?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just write mod.w(path) ? Since mod is of class PM, what's the point of reboxing it in the PM class ?

Comment: If the constructors are private, you should take a look inside the companion object to see if there is some sort of factory method for creating a new instance

Comment: @Tyler I have checked for other methods too , but didnt find one for creating a new instance..

Comment: @C4stor I have updated the code above, please check If I can't call mod.w(path)

Comment: @Garipaso I meant I don't get why you can't access the method you need directly on the ISPM instance, since it should be inheriting it ? If this method is private, and the PM constructor is itself private, the designer of the lib probably doesn't want you to use it ^^